# XSLT sum() with conditions - Returning "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument"

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a set of XML where I'm attempting to sum the wd:Results_Line_Amount if the wd:Group_Deduction_Code = "SIDE FUND", and the person also has a deduction of 'Variable Group Universal Life'. I can sum wd:_Group_Deduction_Code just fine, but when I attempt to add in any conditions for traversing wd:All_Deductions, I get the following error:

"A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:substring()"

How can I sum wd:Results_Line_Amount with these conditions?

I've tried nesting a for-each statement inside the variable declaration but it doesn't sum appropriately.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/test">
<wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Deduction wd:Descriptor="Side Fund">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9e7339f76b5c010ca628fca91701ea24</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Deduction_Code">SIDE</wd:ID>
    </wd:Deduction>
    <wd:Group_Deduction>SIDE FUND</wd:Group_Deduction>
    <wd:Result_Line_Amount>50</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
    <wd:Payroll_Result_Group>
        <wd:All_Deductions
            wd:Descriptor="Variable Group Universal Life: 9 :05/04/2019 - 05/17/2019  (ABC Bi-weekly):John Doe: 05/17/2019 (Regular) - Complete">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">0edb826acc5e01e7381928fc7209cc1e</wd:ID>
        </wd:All_Deductions>
        <wd:All_Deductions
            wd:Descriptor="Side Fund: 50 :05/04/2019 - 05/17/2019  (ABC Bi-weekly):John Doe: 05/17/2019 (Regular) - Complete">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">0edb826acc5e0190b40928fc7209cb1e</wd:ID>
        </wd:All_Deductions>
        <wd:All_Deductions
            wd:Descriptor="Spouse Critical Illness: 50 :05/04/2019 - 05/17/2019  (ABC Bi-weekly):John Doe: 05/17/2019 (Regular) - Complete">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">0edb826acc5e01fd9ad827fc7209ca1e</wd:ID>
        </wd:All_Deductions>
        <wd:All_Deductions
            wd:Descriptor="Side Fund Spouse: 50 :05/04/2019 - 05/17/2019  (ABC Bi-weekly):John Doe: 05/17/2019 (Regular) - Complete">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">0edb826acc5e01ffc2c827fc7209c91e</wd:ID>
        </wd:All_Deductions>
        <wd:All_Deductions
            wd:Descriptor="VGUL Spouse: 5 :05/04/2019 - 05/17/2019  (ABC Bi-weekly):John Doe: 05/17/2019 (Regular) - Complete">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">0edb826acc5e015d93b827fc7209c81e</wd:ID>
        </wd:All_Deductions>
    </wd:Payroll_Result_Group>
</wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Deduction wd:Descriptor="Side Fund Spouse">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9e7339f76b5c012615df0baa1701f024</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Deduction_Code">SIDESP</wd:ID>
    </wd:Deduction>
    <wd:Group_Deduction>SIDE FUND</wd:Group_Deduction>
    <wd:Result_Line_Amount>50</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
    <wd:Payroll_Result_Group>
        <wd:All_Deductions
            wd:Descriptor="Variable Group Universal Life: 9 :05/04/2019 - 05/17/2019  (ABC Bi-weekly):John Doe: 05/17/2019 (Regular) - Complete">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">0edb826acc5e01e7381928fc7209cc1e</wd:ID>
        </wd:All_Deductions>
        <wd:All_Deductions
            wd:Descriptor="Side Fund: 50 :05/04/2019 - 05/17/2019  (ABC Bi-weekly):John Doe: 05/17/2019 (Regular) - Complete">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">0edb826acc5e0190b40928fc7209cb1e</wd:ID>
        </wd:All_Deductions>
        <wd:All_Deductions
            wd:Descriptor="Spouse Critical Illness: 50 :05/04/2019 - 05/17/2019  (ABC Bi-weekly):John Doe: 05/17/2019 (Regular) - Complete">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">0edb826acc5e01fd9ad827fc7209ca1e</wd:ID>
        </wd:All_Deductions>
        <wd:All_Deductions
            wd:Descriptor="Side Fund Spouse: 50 :05/04/2019 - 05/17/2019  (ABC Bi-weekly):John Doe: 05/17/2019 (Regular) - Complete">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">0edb826acc5e01ffc2c827fc7209c91e</wd:ID>
        </wd:All_Deductions>
        <wd:All_Deductions
            wd:Descriptor="VGUL Spouse: 5 :05/04/2019 - 05/17/2019  (ABC Bi-weekly):John Doe: 05/17/2019 (Regular) - Complete">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">0edb826acc5e015d93b827fc7209c81e</wd:ID>
        </wd:All_Deductions>
    </wd:Payroll_Result_Group>
</wd:Report_Entry>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/test">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xd;&#xa;'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="sumSIDE" select="sum(wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry[wd:Group_Deduction = 'SIDE FUND'][substring(wd:Payroll_Result_Group/wd:All_Deductions/@wd:Descriptor,1,29) = 'Variable Group Universal Life']/wd:Result_Line_Amount)"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am expecting the SUM to return 50, instead it returns an error message of "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:substring(). I get the error. It doesn't like that there are multiple "wd:_All_Deduction" tags.

Comment: Do you definitely want the result to be 50, when both `wd:Report_Entry` elements in your XML match your condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current condition is this...

```
[substring(wd:Payroll_Result_Group/wd:All_Deductions/@wd:Descriptor,1,29) = 'Variable Group Universal Life']
```

But as you mention, there are multiple `wd:Payroll_Result_Group/wd:All_Deductions` elements for each `wd:Report_Entry` element. In XSLT 2.0 when you pass a sequence as an parameter to a string function, it will only work if the sequence consists of no more than 1 entry. (In which case, it uses the string value of the single entry).

The condition you want is this....

```
[wd:Payroll_Result_Group/wd:All_Deductions[substring(@wd:Descriptor,1,29) = 'Variable Group Universal Life']]
```

See it in action here at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1ya2